# Simplification of expression

Tags: real-analysis

we put

\begin{align*}
I&=
\dfrac{1}{2} e^t \dfrac{ (x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2}{[ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^2}
- \dfrac{\nu}{2} \dfrac{e^{2t}}{ [ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^2 }+e^t
- 16 \nu^2 \dfrac{ (x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^3  }{ [ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^3 } \\
&\qquad +16 \nu^3 \dfrac{ x+1 -1/2 e^t} { [ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^3 }
 + 4 \nu \dfrac{ (x+1-1/2 e^t)}{[ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu] }
- 4 \nu \dfrac{(x-e^t +1) (x+1-1/2 e^t)^2}{[ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^2} \\
&\qquad +4 \nu^2 \dfrac{1} {[ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^2} + x -e^t +1 
 +8 \nu^2 \dfrac{x+1-1/2 e^t} {[ ( x+ 1 - 1/2 e^t)^2 + \nu]^2}.
\end{align*}

with $\nu > 0$.

I want to prouve that $I=x+1$ but i could not do it, i don't know if my calculates are false or  the identification who's false.

Please can anyone help me to show if $I=x+1$?

The initial problem is that i have the problem $\partial_t u + u \partial_x u - \nu^2 \partial^2_x u = x+1$ and i want to prove that the function 
$$
u(x,t)= - 4 \nu \dfrac{x+1-1/2 e^t}{(x+1-1/2 e^t)^2 +\nu} - x +e^t -1
$$
is solution of the edp. When i inject $u$ is the left hand of edp, i find $I$. I don't know if there is error in my calculate.

Yhank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What are CASes good for?

Comment: @mati are you missing terms? you have $+ +4\nu\dfrac{(x+1)-1/2e^t)}{[(x+1-1/2e^2)^2+\nu]^3$ in your answer.

Comment: i edit my question